# thrust::copy doesn't work for device_vectors

Tags: cuda, gpu, thrust

I copied this code from the [Thrust documentation](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__copying.html#ga24ccfaaa706a9163ec5117758fdb71b9):

```
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>

int main()
{
  thrust::device_vector<int> vec0(100);
  thrust::device_vector<int> vec1(100);
  thrust::copy(vec0.begin(), vec0.end(), vec1.begin());

  return 0;
}
```

When I run this in Debug mode (VS2012), my program crashes and I get the error `Debug Error! ... R6010 - abort() has been called.` When I run this in Release mode, it still crashes and I get the message `.exe has stopped working`.

However copying from host-to-device works correctly:

```
  thrust::host_vector<int> vec0(100);
  thrust::device_vector<int> vec1(100);
  thrust::copy(vec0.begin(), vec0.end(), vec1.begin());
```

I use GeForce GTX 970, CUDA driver version/runtime version is 7.5, deviceQuery runs without any problem. Host runtime library is in `Multi-threaded (/MT)` mode. Does anybody have an idea what might cause this problem?

Comment: The code your have posted compiles and runs without error for me using the same compiler and CUDA version as you say you are using.

Comment: @talonmies I tried my laptop (VS2013, QuadroK1000M) and the program still crashes. Here is full VS solutions https://goo.gl/FFs1cD or 
https://goo.gl/pFss5E

Comment: what happens if you put a `cudaDeviceSynchronize();` immediately before the `return 0;` statement?  Does that fix the issue?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Unfortunately, it doesn't. cudaGetLastError() shows nothing. However I tried Amazon cloud service and the code runs fine! It seems that it is only Windows problem.

Comment: OK my guess is you are building a win32 project.  Switch to building an x64 (release) project instead, and I think the problem will go away.  Note that when you switch to x64, VS puts the executable in a different path, so don't run the same executable that was built by your win32 project.  Support for 32-bit on windows is disappearing from CUDA.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you! It works! Could you copy your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @RobertCrovella I found that it was not a problem of Thrust at all. In another project I tried to use constant memory and use cudaMemcpyToSymbol() to copy from the device memory. It resulted in crash too. Switching to x64 has also fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few similar questions e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703990/cuda-gdb-crashes-with-thrust-cuda-release-5-5)

To quote a comment :

> "Thrust is known to not compile and run correctly when built for
>   debugging"

And from the [docs](https://code.google.com/p/thrust/wiki/Debugging):

> "nvcc does not support device debugging Thrust code. Thrust functions
>   compiled with (e.g., nvcc -G, nvcc --device-debug 0, etc.) will likely
>   crash."

Comment: I know it. I do not compile for debugging. Just in Release mode.

Comment: Did you clean before building/running?

Comment: Yes, I did and it didn't help.

Comment: Can you try, Properties -> Debug -> Enable unmanaged code debugging (Disable it). Let me know if it fixes.

Comment: I cannot find such setting in Visual Studio 2012/2013